# Can't generate the new Maven project

Tags: maven, fabric8

I'm following the [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/transaction_guide/txnintro-gettingstarted) from Red Hat and I'm running a query in maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=io.fabric8.archetypes
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-camel-cbr-archetype
-DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0.redhat-630187
-DgroupId=tutorial
-DartifactId=tx-jms-router
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
-Dfabric8-profile=tx-jms-router-profile
```

But I see an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3
.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype doe
s not exist (io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-camel-cbr-archetype:1.2.0.redhat-630187
) -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to create a maven project using the Jboss Developer Studio, but the result was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8.archetypes/karaf-camel-cbr-archetype/1.2.0.redhat-630187)

...you'll notice the artifact is not in central maven repo.
So the problem is that you need to tell Maven to look also in non-default places.

Therefore, you need to edit your `settings.xml` and add an extra repository (in the above link, you are pointed towards the right repository).

https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/

Edit: Related to adding repositories in settings.xml (related to your comment below). There are two things wrong with your listing:

- You're missing an `activeProfiles` tag as seen [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) (you only have `activeProfile`)
- The fact that you were missing the `activeProfiles` tag and you DID NOT got a Maven error leads me to believe that you modified the wrong `settings.xml`. Did you tried to modify the one from the `.m2` folder?

Comment: Yep, I tried to create a maven project using the Jboss Developer Studio, where I could manually select the repository Red Hat, but the result is the same

Comment: Sorry, I suggested a different thing (adding the repository in `settings.xml`). I continue to believe that is going to solve your problem.

Comment: I add this on my settings.xml, but result is the same                                               <profiles>
 <profile>
   <id>jboss-ga-repository</id>
   <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-ga-repository</id>
    <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
    <releases>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
   <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
   </repositories>
 </profile>
 </profiles>
<activeProfile>jboss-ga-repository</activeProfile>

Comment: yes, I lose `activeProfiles` tags. Sorry for my inattention) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.open.iona.com/maven2
```